# Attribute Error when trying to use PyTorch

Tags: pytorch

I am getting this error when trying to use PyTorch

```
import torch

z = torch.zeros(5,3)
print (z)
print(z.datatype)
```

```
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'torch' has no attribute 'zeros' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

I am on python 3.9 because PyTorch does not work with more modern versions

I tried reimporting with pip3 and it says that I already have it downloaded

Answer (score 0):

#### Show a minimal, reproducible example

In an empty python program, show what is needed for any third party to replicate your problem.

This means:

- import statement
- just enough statements to trigger the error

And please state version of Pytorch as well as the version of Python that you did give.

Comment: I added the code and frankly I do not know the PyTorch version as it won't let me recognize it exists

Comment: So "import torch" gave an error? What error? If it didn't give an error, then you know it exists and has imported. In the operating system command line try `pip3 show torch` which should give you the version.